# SQL in-line equivalent to intersect

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is there an inline sql command that is similar to or produces the same results as `intersect`? If not is there a way to rewrite the query so it is in one query rather than using `intersect`?

My current sql query is:

```
SELECT 
  c.Log_Link 
FROM 
  Classes c INNER JOIN 
  ClassValues cv ON c.Class_Link = cv.Class_Link INNER JOIN 
  ClassSelection cs ON cv.ClassSelection_Link = cs.ClassSelection_Link
WHERE 
  cs.classselection_link IN (95,1)
```

But what I'm really after is:

```
SELECT 
  c.Log_Link 
FROM 
  Classes c INNER JOIN 
  ClassValues cv ON c.Class_Link = cv.Class_Link INNER JOIN 
  ClassSelection cs ON cv.ClassSelection_Link = cs.ClassSelection_Link
WHERE 
  cs.classselection_link = 95 
INTERSECT 
SELECT 
  c.Log_Link 
FROM 
  Classes c INNER JOIN 
  ClassValues cv ON c.Class_Link = cv.Class_Link INNER JOIN 
  ClassSelection cs ON cv.ClassSelection_Link = cs.ClassSelection_Link
WHERE 
  cs.classselection_link = 1
```

Thanks

Comment: Does your second query actually return any data? Surely, `cs.classselection_link` cannot be equal to 1 and 95 which is what, in effect, you are asking for in the second query.

Comment: Yes it does, basically classValues hold the class_link and the classSelection_link. Its basically a many-to-many relationship and I want all classes that contact both the passed classSelections.

Comment: Why do you not want to use `INTERSECT`?  It exists for a reason, and that is cases like yours.

There are other ways to write the query, but they will be a lot less clear than just using `INTERSECT` like you did in your example.

Is there a reason you want to obfuscate the code?

Comment: @JNK: +1 for JNK's comment. Only reason I can think of is preformance. How well does SQL-Server optimize `INTERSECT` clauses?

Comment: And @Simon: using `INTERSECT` does not mean you have 2 queries. You still have 1 query (with 2 subqueries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  c.Log_Link 
FROM 
  Classes c INNER JOIN 
  ClassValues cv1 ON c.Class_Link = cv1.Class_Link INNER JOIN 
  ClassSelection cs1 ON cv1.ClassSelection_Link = cs1.ClassSelection_Link

INNER JOIN
  ClassValues cv2 ON c.Class_Link = cv2.Class_Link INNER JOIN 
  ClassSelection cs2 ON cv2.ClassSelection_Link = cs2.ClassSelection_Link

WHERE 
    cs1.classselection_link = 95 
  AND
    cs2.classselection_link = 1
```

or with **GROUP BY**:

```
SELECT 
  c.Log_Link 
FROM 
  Classes c INNER JOIN 
  ClassValues cv ON c.Class_Link = cv.Class_Link INNER JOIN 
  ClassSelection cs ON cv.ClassSelection_Link = cs.ClassSelection_Link
WHERE 
  cs.classselection_link IN (95,1)
GROUP BY
  c.Class_Link
HAVING
  COUNT(c.Class_Link) = 2
```

and since you don't really need the `ClassSelection` table:

```
SELECT 
  c.Log_Link 
FROM 
  Classes c INNER JOIN 
  ClassValues cv ON c.Class_Link = cv.Class_Link
WHERE 
  cv.ClassSelection_Link IN (95,1)
GROUP BY
  c.Class_Link
HAVING
  COUNT(c.Class_Link) = 2
```

As gbn pointed, I assumed that `(Class_Link, ClassSelection_Link)` is `UNIQUE` in table `ClassValues`.

If that is not true, then the HAVING clause at the last 2 queries should be changed to :

```
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT cv.ClassSelection_Link) = 2
```

Comment: What if there are 3 rows with classselection_link = 95 from the JOIN? Should be `COUNT(DISTINCT cs.classselection) = 2`, no?

Comment: @gbn: You are right, I assumed that `(Class_Link, ClassSelection_Link)` is `UNIQUE` in table `ClassValues`. Your correction works in any case.

Answer (score 2):

May be using inner join...

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
          c.Log_Link 
        FROM 
          Classes c INNER JOIN 
          ClassValues cv ON c.Class_Link = cv.Class_Link INNER JOIN 
          ClassSelection cs ON cv.ClassSelection_Link = cs.ClassSelection_Link
        WHERE 
          cs.classselection_link = 95 
    ) T1
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
          c.Log_Link 
        FROM 
          Classes c INNER JOIN 
          ClassValues cv ON c.Class_Link = cv.Class_Link INNER JOIN 
          ClassSelection cs ON cv.ClassSelection_Link = cs.ClassSelection_Link
        WHERE 
          cs.classselection_link = 1
    ) T2
ON
    T1.Log_Link = T2.Log_Link
```

Answer (score 2):

INTERSECT and EXISTS are the same semantically. And you don't need so many tables

```
SELECT 
  c.Log_Link 
FROM 
  Classes c
WHERE 
  EXISTS (
      SELECT * FROM ClassValues cv
      WHERE c.Class_Link = cv.Class_Link AND cv.classselection_link = 95)
AND
  EXISTS (
      SELECT * FROM ClassValues cv
      WHERE c.Class_Link = cv.Class_Link AND cv.classselection_link = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you just want distinct.  You're trying to get a unique set of c.Log_Link that matches either criteria, correct?  If so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  c.Log_Link 
FROM 
  Classes c INNER JOIN 
  ClassValues cv ON c.Class_Link = cv.Class_Link INNER JOIN 
  ClassSelection cs ON cv.ClassSelection_Link = cs.ClassSelection_Link
WHERE 
  cs.classselection_link IN (95,1)
```

Edit:  I see your clarification.  I think joining derived tables as amit_g suggested would be the way to go.

I'd tweak it just a bit though:

```
SELECT 
  c.Log_Link 
FROM 
  Classes c INNER JOIN 
  ClassValues cv ON c.Class_Link = cv.Class_Link INNER JOIN 
  ClassSelection cs ON cv.ClassSelection_Link = cs.ClassSelection_Link
  INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 
          c.Log_Link 
        FROM 
          Classes c INNER JOIN 
          ClassValues cv ON c.Class_Link = cv.Class_Link INNER JOIN 
          ClassSelection cs ON cv.ClassSelection_Link = cs.ClassSelection_Link
        WHERE 
          cs.classselection_link = 1
    ) T2 ON c.Log_Link = T2.Log_Link
WHERE 
  cs.classselection_link = 95
```

Comment: Thanks but distinct doesn't work. I want it to return all the Log_links associated to 95 and 1 whereas DISTINCT returns all the log_links just removing any duplicates.